# Canvas and Apache Permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I'm setting up a test server for canvas-LMS. However when I try to access it after following all the steps in the production start guide to install all the requirements and do all the initial setup I get the terrible "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

The default site that apache provides worked fine but when i registered canvas I got the error. Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/canvas:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName canvas.example.com
  ServerAlias files.canvas.example.com
  ServerAdmin youremail@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/canvas/public
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/health_check
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/canvas_errors.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/canvas_access.log combined
  SetEnv RAILS_ENV production
  <Directory /var/canvas/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName canvas.example.com
  ServerAlias files.canvas.example.com
  ServerAdmin example@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/canvas/public
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/canvas_errors.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/canvas_ssl_access.log combined
  SSLEngine on
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
  # the following ssl certificate files are generated for you from the ssl-cert package.
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  SetEnv RAILS_ENV production
  <Directory /var/canvas/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the default file. I haven't changed anything at all.
The start guide: https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start

I'm newish to apache so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with both Rails/Passenger and dealing directly with Canvas, it doesn't sound to me like the request is being handled by Passenger, and as a result, is trying to pull the directory listing of /var/canvas/public, which is likely disabled based on the error you're getting.

I would double check that the Passenger module is actually being loaded; you should be ale to confirm with:

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`

You should see something along the lines of "passenger_module (shared)" - if you'll need to ensure it is loaded. If you do see it, you'll want to make sure that it is properly configured (you may need to set the PassengerRoot and PassengerDefaultRuby directives, depending on your deployment). You may want to revisit [the Production Start docs](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start#configure-passenger-with-apache) section regarding this for a bit more detail.

Let me know if you're still having trouble; I'm somewhat familiar with dealing with Canvas.

edit:

If Passenger is in fact loaded but still showing a blank page, it could be that, as I mentioned before, there are some missing Passenger configuration directives. I can duplicate the behavior you're describing by comment out PassengerDefaultRuby and PassengerRoot directives from my passenger.conf. The path you'll want to see these to will vary by your system/deployment method, but to give you an idea, here is what mine looks like on a cPanel sandbox server using RVM:

`PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.19`
`PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby`

You should be able to get the ideal settings for these directives by re-running `passenger-install-apache2-module` - it should give you the directives on the output.

You can see a bit more about these directives in the [Passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger).

I could be off base here, but it sounds like this might be your issue.

Comment: Whoah! That's a lot of errors! I'm going to see if I can figure some of them out. I'll comment back here if i can't fix it!       Edit: I'm an idiot. Forgot to use sudo with that command. So there's a lot of modules loaded and passenger is loaded.

Comment: Well, did everything I could find online but nothing worked. I don't think passenger is the problem. It's indicating as everything loading properly

Comment: updated my answer, re: passenger configuration. it may or may not help. I'll let you know if I think or anything else.